# 4-acceleration in 1+3 formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor

I need to calculate $\nabla_b A_a$ where $A_a=u^b \nabla_b u_a $ is the 4-acceleration.  I know the result but I cannot see the way to arrive to it. The result is

$$
\nabla_bA_a=D_bA_a+\frac{1}{3}\Theta u_aA_b+u_a\left(\sigma_{bc}-\omega_{bc}\right)A^c-\left(A_au_b\right)^\dot{}+A_aA_b
$$

where $(T^{abc...}_{\ \ \ efg...})^\dot{}=u^m \nabla_mT^{abc...}_{\ \ \ efg...}$ is the time derivative and

$$
D_mT_{abc...}^{def...}=h_m^qh_a^gh_b^kh_c^j\dots h_p^dh_r^eh_s^f\dots\nabla_qT_{gkj...}^{prs...}. 
$$

is the spatial derivative, where $h_{ab}=g_{ab}+u_au_b$ is the projector tensor.

I know too that

$$
\nabla_bu_a=\frac{1}{3}\Theta h_{ab}+\sigma_{ab}+\omega_{ab}-A_au_b. 
$$

> Some hint?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to see your result is to take the right hand side of your given equation and expand it, using the second and third equality. Also remember that u is a unit vector orthogonal to its covariant derivative .